# this.selector in JQuery plugin - Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, this

I've seen many questions regarding this errors, none of which was very helpful for this situation.

I'm trying to write a JQuery plugin, but I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined". The seems to be associated with "this". For example, this seems to work fine:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    var offsetBot = window.innerHeight - (($("#textBox1").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) + $("#textBox1").height());
    console.log(offsetBot);
  });
```

But this inside of the function below, I get the error..

```
$.fn.offBottom= function() {

$(window).scroll(function() {

      if (!this.length) {
        console.log("no element selected")
        return;
      } else{
        var offsetBot = window.innerHeight - (($(this.selector).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) + $(this.selector).height());
      }});
  };

  $("#textBox1").offBottom();

});
```

I've tried using "this", "$(this)", and "this.selector" all with no luck.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've placed your `$(this)` context inside `$(window)` scroll function. That is why you are getting the DOM's element [undefined] thus you cannot get its `top` property

You might need to initialize your DOM's element before that like this:

```
$.fn.offBottom = function() {
    var oElement = $(this); // $(this) will refer to the DOM that called the [offBottom] property method

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (oElement.length) {
            console.log("no element selected");
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log(oElement.offset().top);
            var offsetBot = window.innerHeight - ((oElement.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) + $(this.selector).height());
        }});
};

$("#textBox1").offBottom();
```

Hope this helps for your case

Comment: Oh that helped alright.  I also had to change '$(this.selector).height' to 'oElement.height()' afterward. Thanks